# Java Server certificate chains not associated to the SNI field

Tags: java, openssl, tls1.2, sni, tls1.3

I'm running on Java 11.

```
>     bash-4.4$ java -version
>     openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
>     OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-suse-3.62.1-x8664)
>     OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-suse-3.62.1-x8664, mixed mode)
```

My scenario is this:

- My TLS Client uses the SNI extension and sets the Server Name field to the CN field of the Root CA's SubjectDN.
- My Server shall use the SNI to select the Intermediate CA certificate to send together with the Server certificate in the TLS handshake.
- The ServerCertificate is cross-signed by two SubCAs according to this picture:

```
RootCA1        RootCA2
|              |
+--+           |
    |          |
    +-->Sub2*  +-> Sub2
        |          |
        +--------->+-> ServerCertificate
```

Note that:

- Sub2 and Sub2* have the same SubjectDN, but they have different IssuerDN.
- Sub2's IssuerDN is RootCA2
- Sub2*'s IssuerDN is RootCA1

In the Server KeyStore I have two entries:

- [KeyStore-Entry-0] {alias: "Primary", key, [ServerCertificate, Sub2]}
- [KeyStore-Entry-1] {alias: "Secondary", key, [ServerCertificate, Sub2*]}

The SNIMatcher, added into the SSL Parameters, in the Java Server is set to accept something like "RootCA*"

I use openssl to test this setup in that way:

```
openssl s_client -servername 'RootCA1' -CAfile ./RootCA1.pem -connect localhost:4321
openssl s_client -servername 'RootCA2' -CAfile ./RootCA2.pem -connect localhost:4321
```

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**
I was expecting that Java KeyManager addressed SNI requests according to the IssuerDN field of the trusted Sub2s certificates. But it doesn't work.

On Client Hello with SNI set to "RootCA1" my server shall return the chain "ServerCertificate + Sub2*"
On Client Hello with SNI set to "RootCA2" my server shall return the chain "ServerCertificate + Sub2"

**OBSERVED BEHAVIOR:**
Unfortunately the observed behavior is that my server always returns the chain "ServerCertificate + Sub2" and the following handshake fails

```
openssl s_client -servername 'RootCA1' -CAfile ./RootCA1.pem -connect localhost:4321
...
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
...
```

I tried with no success to play with the aliases in my Keystore or with the key order...

Any idea?
What I'm doing wrong?
How can my Server return the chain "ServerCertificate + Sub2*" when the client's SNI is set to RootCA1?

Thank you!

**SOLUTION**

I managed to find a solution and want to share it for those who will meet the same problem.

- The first step was to set the SNI Matcher in the SSL Parameters using a proper regular expression. The effect of the javax.net.ssl.SNIMatcher is just to reject wrong client requests returning a TLS Alert "Unrecognized Name".
- The second step was to populate the KeyStore using aliases in lower case.
- The third step was to extend the X509ExtendedKeyManager with my own implementation to override the method chooseServerAlias. The method chooseServerAlias (and similarly chooseEngineServerAlias depending on the implementation) is needed to inspect the SNI sent by openssl client and to return the exact keystore alias used later to get the correct certificate chain.

Here's the code snapshot.

Note that SniKeyManager is wrapping the ExtendedKeyManager built by KeyManagerFactory, then it is passed to SSLContext.init.
Probably there's some better solution, but I prefer to keep the original X509ExtendedKeyManager build by KeyManagerFactory that also owns the KeyStore.

Here's how I set my SniKeyManager into the SSLContext:

```
        for (KeyManager keyManager : keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers()) {
            if (keyManager instanceof X509ExtendedKeyManager) {
                x509KeyManager = (X509ExtendedKeyManager) keyManager;
                break;
            }
        }
        SniKeyManager sniKeyManager = new SniKeyManager(x509KeyManager);
        sslContext.init(new KeyManager[] {sniKeyManager}, null, null);
```

Here's a snapshot of SniKeyManager:

```
public final class SniKeyManager extends X509ExtendedKeyManager {
    private final X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager;

    public SniKeyManager(X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager) {
        this.keyManager = keyManager;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        String result = this.keyManager.chooseServerAlias(keyType, issuers, socket);
        //chooseServerAlias may return null on invalid keyType
        
        if (result != null && socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) socket;
            ExtendedSSLSession session = (ExtendedSSLSession) s.getHandshakeSession();
            List<SNIServerName> snis = session.getRequestedServerNames();
            for (SNIServerName sniValue : snis) {
                result = getKeyStoreAliasBySni(sniValue);
                if (null != result) break;
            }
        }
        //note that result must be still in lower case
        return result;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
        return keyManager.getCertificateChain(alias);
    }

    @Override
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {
        return keyManager.getPrivateKey(alias);
    }
}
```

The method SniKeyManager.getKeyStoreAliasBySni contains the logic for binding the SNI value to the keystore alias.

The Java class ServerHandshaker ([link](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u-backup-06-sep-2018/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/ServerHandshaker.java)) handles the TLS Handshake by using the X509ExtendedKeyManager. There you can see that the value returned by chooseServerAlias will be the entry for getPrivateKey and getCertificateChain.

Comment: This 'problem' occurs when you use SNI to contain something other than the domain name of the server because SNI is _defined_ by all applicable standards to always and only contain the domain name of the server. Using anything else is prohibited, and no software designed to comply to standards is allowed to support anything else. While this is well-researched and (admirably) clear, I can't vote for it as useful because it is in fact harmful..